# How to go to file (gf) in vim where extension is not mentioned?

Tags: vim, ansible

In the below ansible code, when i move my cursor to get_service_restart_count.yml and type 'gf' in vim then it open that file .

```
- name: Delete PVC
  include_role:
    name: kube
    tasks_from: delete_pvc

- name: get service restart count again
  include: get_service_restart_count.yml
```

But when i try the same with `delete_pvc` (where extension is missing) it is not moving to file. it throws error

> E447: Can't find file "delete_pvc" in path

.

almost all of the tasks_from will not have extension in it.

Is there any option in vim to move to the file name where extension is missing?

Comment: `gf` works even on filenames without extension. where are these files located? are they in the same directory of `get_service_restart_count.yml`? see also `:help path`

Comment: The actual file name is delete_pvc.yml only. But in ansible for tasks_from we mention the filename without extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `gf` on a filename without extension, Vim tries every suffix in `:help 'suffixesadd'`.

In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/yaml.vim` (Unix derivatives) or `%userprofile%\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\yaml.vim` (Windows), add this line:

```
setlocal suffixesadd+=.yml
```

(Which should be in the default ftplugin, IMO.)

Comment: some times they are using .yml ,and other time they are using .yaml. In that case should i add both?

Comment: Yes, add whatever makes sense in your context.